# Function with template and Priority Queue

Tags: c++, templates, priority-queue

I'm trying to write Dijkstra's algorithm with Fibonacci Heap and Priority Queue. So I have a class (struct) for Fibonacci Heap

```
template<class T>
struct Fib {
    ...
};
```

and a function

```
template <template <class> class T>
void dijkstra(...) {
    T<std::pair<double, int> > heap;
    ...
}
```

The problem is:

```
dijkstra<Fib>(...);                 // OK
dijkstra<std::priority_queue>(...); // doesn't compile
```

Why doesn't this compile, and how can I write it properly?

Comment: std::priority_queue is a template by itself, you haven't instantiated the template with the type of object it will be holding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a parameter like:

```
template<class> class T
```

that expects a class template with a **single** template argument. `Fib` is such a class template, it just takes `T`. However, [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) doesn't take a single template parameter. It takes three, even though two are defaulted:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

If you're using C++11, you could simply enhance `dijkstra` to take an arbitrary class template:

```
template<template<class...> class T>
//                     ^^^
void dijkstra(...) {
```

Or write a single-template-parameter alias for `std::priority_queue`:

```
template <class T>
using vector_less_pq = std::priority_queue<T>;
```